# Is perforce "connection reset by peer" error really an error ?

Tags: perforce

P4 Server version: P4D/LINUX26X86_64/2013.2/938876 (2014/09/23)
on RHEL6

While running a perl script using p4perl, I trap an error something like this...

```
if ($p4->ErrorCount() {
    foreach $err ($p4->Errors) {
        print "$err\n";
    }
}
```

These errors pop up in a nondeterministic way, sometimes I get them, sometimes not.  But if I trap an error with the code above, and I get ...

```
TCP receive failed.
read: socket:
Connection reset by peer
```

Is that a real error (given that, apparently, the connection was reset ?)
Can I ignore this?  Will it run the thing I wanted to run after resetting the connection ?  Or do I need to rerun that command ?

I fear that the problem may be rooted in the fact that the perl script does a fork earlier on and the $p4 handle I have was sent to the forked process.  Could I do something like this to detect and remedy this

```
use P4;
our $p4 = new P4;

<perl forks off a new process...>

if(!($p4-IsConnected)) {
    $p4->SetCwd("$CWD");
        if($p4->ErrorCount()) {handle_p4_error();} 
    $p4->Connect();
        if($p4->ErrorCount()) {handle_p4_error();}
}
....etc....
exit;

sub handle_p4_err {
    print "<<<P4 ERROR>>>\n";
    foreach $err ($p4->Errors) {
        print "$err\n";
    }
exit;
}
```

Or will the SetCwd fail for lack of connection?

Could the P4 admin be setting some sort of timeout (kill connection after x minutes of inactivity) ?

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 2):

> Is that a real error (given that, apparently, the connection was reset ?)

Yes; the connection with the server was terminated.

> Can I ignore this?  Will it run the thing I wanted to run after resetting the connection?

No.

> Or do I need to rerun that command ?

Yes; I think you will also need to reopen the connection first.

```
$p4->Connect();
    if($p4->ErrorCount()) {handle_p4_error();}
```

That is the general pattern, although if the connection fails you probably want to bail out since nothing you do after that point is going to work (and in most cases it means something is configured wrong).

> Or will the SetCwd fail for lack of connection?

No; that's purely a client side action and does not talk to the server.

> Could the P4 admin be setting some sort of timeout (kill connection after x minutes of inactivity) ?

That is one possibility -- does your script hold an idle connection open?  That's considered poor manners since enough of those will constitute a DDoS attack by preventing any new connections from being opened.  Another possibility is that there was some other network failure (your VPN connection went down, etc).

Comment: Thanks Sam:  And the code to test IsConnected ? (BTW, I forgot the "()" after IsConnected)  ? Does that look like a good way to detect a missing connection and establish a new one ? (given it's not a netwoek problem or something like that)

Comment: I'm not sure offhand whether IsConnected() will detect error cases or whether it's only checking for "clean" connection severance -- I know that in the C++ API you typically want to check the Error and Final() if it's something fatal before re-opening the connection.

Answer (score 1):

In my particular case, I believe the problem had to do with the fork in the perl script.  Perhaps the handle was passed to the forked process and this interfered with attempts to reconnect in the main process thread. I had a similar problem with a DB connection.  The remedy was similar as well....

What seemed to work was to unconditionally disconnect from P4 just before the fork and unconditionally reconnect right after.  The forked process didn't need a P4 connection, so this is OK (in my particular case).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was I needed to make an ssh connection to the perforce server, but I hadn't added the correct ssh key.  You can list ssh keys added to your session with this command:

```
ssh-add -L
```